# Dissapearing menu item

Tags: sql, asp-classic, dreamweaver

Firstly, please forgive me if the way I ask this question doesn't make sense as I'm not sure how to put it, but here goes.

I have a list of items in a menu which link to a records in a database. The user can click on a link which opens a form to allow alterations to the record, however, if the field starts with a link (`<a href...`), then it doesn't show up in the list.

The SQL code is:

```
SELECT ResourceID,  LEFT (ResourceContent, 40) AS ResourceContent
FROM tblResources
WHERE YouTubeLink IS NULL AND DisplayRecord = 1
ORDER BY PositionNumber ASC
```

The output for the SQL code is:

```
Record  ResourceID  ResourceContent
1       1           <p><a href="../../other-files/Annual-Rep
2       2           <p>Click here to see the most recent MfM
3       3           <p>Click here to read the latest newslet
4       7           <p>Here is a load of text that will be u
```

The menu code is:

```
<h3><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%></h3>

<ul>

<li class="menuHeading"><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></li>
<li class="menuList brown" style="margin-left:-15px">Documents</li>
<% 
While ((RepeatNonMedia__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsNonMedia.EOF)) 
%>
  <li id="resourceMenuList"><a href="resources-modify-document-record.asp?idVal=<%=(rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceID").Value)%>"><%=(rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceContent").Value)%>...</li>
  <% 
  RepeatNonMedia__index=RepeatNonMedia__index+1
  RepeatNonMedia__numRows=RepeatNonMedia__numRows-1
  rsNonMedia.MoveNext()
Wend
%>

<li class="menuList brown" style="margin-left:-15px">Videos</li>
<% 
While ((RepeatMedia__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsMedia.EOF)) 
%>
  <li id="resourceMenuList"><a href="resources-modify-video-record.asp?idVal=<%=(rsMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceID").Value)%>"><%=(rsMedia.Fields.Item("YouTubeCaption").Value)%>...</a></li>
  <% 
  RepeatMedia__index=RepeatMedia__index+1
  RepeatMedia__numRows=RepeatMedia__numRows-1
  rsMedia.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
<% 
While ((RepeatAddRecord__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsAddRecord.EOF)) 
%>
<%
    fName = Replace (rsAddRecord.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value," ","-")
    fName = Lcase(fName)
%>
  <li class="menuHeading"><a href="<% Response.Write(fName) %>-modify-record.asp"><%=(rsAddRecord.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></a></li>
  <% 
  RepeatAddRecord__index=RepeatAddRecord__index+1
  RepeatAddRecord__numRows=RepeatAddRecord__numRows-1
  rsAddRecord.MoveNext()
Wend
%>

<li class="menuHeading"><a href="learn-more-modify-record.asp?mmID=<%=(rsAddRecordExtra.Fields.Item("MainMenuID").Value)%>&smID=<%=(rsAddRecordExtra.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value)%>"><%=(rsAddRecordExtra.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></a></li>
</ul>
```

The output to the webpage is similar to:

```
Learn More

Resources
   Documents
      Click here to see the most recent MfM...
      Click here to read the latest newslet...
      Here is a load of text that will be u...
  Videos
      Money for Madagascar - Our Work in Pictu...
      Money for Madagascar - Our Work in Pictu...
      Bambi's mother comes back from the dead ...
Case Studies
Friends Of MfM
The Welsh Connection
```

As you can see, the SQL outputs the record but the code doesn't recognise it. If the link is outside the 40th character there is no problem, however, if the link is inside of the 40th character, the listing truncates to the `<a href...` tag.

I've tried using `<% Response.Write() %>` to surround the `<li>` tag info but no luck. If I remove all formatting, use just basic HTML code, still no luck.

I thought about using a regexp to remove the link code (including the end tag) but I don't no enough about regexp to write it.

Any hoo, can you help me resolve this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did.

I removed the code limiting the characters from the SQL statement. I then replaced the `<a\b[^>]*>` in safetyOtter's code with `<[^>]*>`. This regex code removes all the html code in the field. I then added more code that then renamed the regex output. This I then used in the `<a>` tag to limit the number of characters displayed.

New SQL code

```
SELECT ResourceID, ResourceContent
FROM tblResources
WHERE YouTubeLink IS NULL AND DisplayRecord = 1
ORDER BY PositionNumber ASC
```

The regex code

```
<%
set regex = New RegExp
regex.Pattern = "<[^>]*>"
regex.Global = true
regex.IgnoreCase = true
%>
```

Code to rename the regex added after the `<% While... %>` statement

```
<%
ResourceContent = regex.Replace((rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceContent").Value),"")
%>
```

HTML code

```
<a href="resources-modify-document-record.asp?idVal=<%=(rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceID").Value)%>"><%=LEFT(ResourceContent,40)%>...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, try replacing

```
<%=(rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceContent").Value)%>
```

with

```
<%=Replace((rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceContent").Value),"<a ","<gibberish")%>
```

Edit:

just above your replace someplace safe, prolly just over the start of the while:

```
set regex = New RegExp
regex.Pattern = "<a\b[^>]+>"
regex.Global = true
regex.IgnoreCase = true
```

then replace

```
<%=(rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceContent").Value)%>
```

with

```
<%=regex.Replace((rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceContent").Value),"")%>
```

Comment: OK, tried your suggestion and what happens is quite odd and not easy to explain. Where the first part of the output should be displayed is a blank line. It's not even putting in your replacement value. However, if you remove the `<` from `<gibberish` it outputs `gibberishhref="../../other-files/Annual-Rep...`. Could be on to a winner here.

Comment: This time the line has disappeared again.

Comment: Is the ResourceContent above limited to the characters that are shown above?  I have been assuming you were truncatung it for display.  If the data has an incomplete <a href tag inside of it, it will be blank and i dunno if there is anything we could replace it with that would look good.  We could change the pattern of the regex too `<a\b[^>*>` and add "No Data" to the end of the regex.Replace instead of the "" that is there now.

Comment: The ResourceContent is limited to just 40 characters so that it fits within a given space. A link could appear anywhere in the 40 characters. If you add a link further in the line, the rest disappears, ie: if you add a link to the word 'here' in `Click here to see the most recent MfM...` this will only display `Click `. I've just tried your latest suggestion but it's still the same result. It seems just removing an `<a ... </a>` statement isn't as easy as I thought.

Comment: It's just that the </a> may or may not be there depending on how long the link is.  What do you want to display if there's a long link in the ResourceContent?

Comment: Hello again from a damp UK. I removed the 40 character limit from the SQL code and it works perfectly, so it would seem your idea about the length of the link is correct. However, the link remains clickable but not the rest of the menu item.

Comment: Try replacing the <a with <span  `<%=Replace((rsNonMedia.Fields.Item("ResourceContent").Value),"<a ","<span")%>`

Comment: Hi safetyOtter. I've managed to sort the problem using your guidance. I'll add what I did shortly. Can I take this opportunity to say thank you for your help, I couldn't have sorted this without it.

Comment: Great! I was glad to help.  I look forward to seeing how you got it working.